# Space between items in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using `bootstrap 4` and i have a list of items that i display like this :

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="card col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 item-wr"  *ngFor="let item of items">
        ...
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

In my desktop view with Google Chrome i can see 3 items by row but the problem is there is no space between columns. so i add a class `item-wr`

```
.item-wr {
    margin: 10px; 
}
```

But here also the line breaks and i see just 2 items, with some space on the right of the row.

So how can i keep my 3 items per row `col-md-4` with space between them ?

P.S i want no space in the beginning or the ending of each row. the first col of each row must not have some `margin-left` and the last col of each row must not have some `margin-right`

Comment: use padding and box-sizing instead of margin

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `card` class inside `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12`. because `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12` this class taking itself padding and give space so you can apply design related class inside column class.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12">
      <div class="card item-wr">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12">
       <div class="card item-wr">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12">
       <div class="card item-wr">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding utility classes available with bootstrap 4 like `pr-2` for padding right by 2 spacing units. Refer [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

P.S. margin will add space outside of the box-model and hence you should use padding to prevent line breaks. For more info refer [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/set-css-margins-padding-cool-layout-tricks/)